# C struct problem

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to learn about structs in C, but i do not understand why i cannot assign the title as i my example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct book_information {
 char title[100];
 int year;
 int page_count;
}my_library;


main()
{

 my_library.title = "Book Title"; // Problem is here, but why?
 my_library.year = 2005;
 my_library.page_count = 944;

 printf("\nTitle: %s\nYear: %d\nPage count: %d\n", my_library.title, my_library.year, my_library.page_count);
 return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```
books.c: In function ‘main’:
books.c:13: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from type ‘char *’
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

LHS is an array, RHS is a pointer.  You need to use `strcpy` to put the pointed-to bytes into the array.

```
strcpy(my_library.title, "Book Title");
```

Take care that you do not copy source data > 99 bytes long here as you need space for a string-terminating null ('\0') character.

The compiler was trying to tell you what was wrong in some detail:

> error: incompatible types when
>   assigning to type ‘char[100]’ from
>   type ‘char *’

Look at your original code again and see if this makes more sense now.

Comment: Thanks, after adding "#include <strings.h>" the program compiles and works as expected. All examples i have found, has been using scanf or gets to fill the strings, and this makes sense to me now.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  I would consider the `strncpy` alternatives, unless you are sure your input data will always be small enough to fit.

Comment: Though including strings.h may happen to work on your implementation, you really should be including string.h to declare strcpy.

Comment: Would recommend using `strncpy` over `strcpy` to make sure you're not going over array size limit.

Comment: I was going over structures today, and I came across the same problem. Of course, this solved my answer. But I don't see the logic behind it. Can someone explain why didn't C allow to equate a char array with a char pointer? After all, a pointer to an array is the first element of the array itself.

Answer (score 6):

As the message says, the issue is you are trying to assign incompatible types: `char*` and `char[100]`.  You need to use a function like `strncpy` to copy the data between the 2

```
strncpy(my_library.title, "Book Title", sizeof(my_library.title));
```

Comment: `sizeof(my_library.title)-1`, no?

Comment: @Oli, indeed.  Mentally smacked myself for the over site.

Answer (score 3):

`title` is a *character array* - these are not assignable in C. Use [`strcpy(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strcpy/).

Answer (score 1):

char* and char[100] are different types.

You want to copy those char elements inside the .title buffer.

```
strncpy(my_library.title, "Book Title", sizeof(my_library.title));
```